# Unable to execute insert statement

Tags: php, mysqli

```
if(true){
    //query
    $insertAccount = mysqli_prepare($connection,"INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email), VALUES (?,?,?)");
    //bind 
    $bindSuccess = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insertAccount, 'sss', $username,$password,$email);
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($insertAccount)){
        header("Location: welcome.php");
    }else{
        header("Location: signup.php");
    }

}
```

Hello, i have the above code snippet from my php code, i always get directed to signup.php, and the statement is not inserted, what am i doing wrong here? i am very new to php and mysqli statements for php.

The if(true) is just for me to test that im certain the block is executed.

Comment: In your query says: `(username, password, email)` and in the bind: `$username,$email,$password` The order is wrong. Try: `$username,$password,$email`

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_stmt_execute return a false value in case of error. You should confirm there is no error in your query:

```
if(true){
    //query
    $insertAccount = mysqli_prepare($connection,"INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email), VALUES (?,?,?)");
    //bind 
    $bindSuccess = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insertAccount, 'sss', $username,$password,$email);
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($insertAccount)){
        header("Location: welcome.php");
    }else{
        printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($insertAccount));
        //header("Location: signup.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: i receceived a error whereby the prepare statement is returning a boolean value, that means my statement is wrong, but i dont see any error in it.what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! "INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email), VALUES (?,?,?)" my error was in the sql statement, there is a extra comma!!!!

Comment: A good idea is to run the query in phpmyadmin or something similar. This way you can see if the problem is in the query or in your code.